# estoy aprendiendo python quiero saber como hago esto?

Tags: python, string, algoritmos

LEER DOS PALABRAS MOSTRARLAS CRUZANDOSE EN LA PRIMERA LETRA QUE COINCIDA

tiene que ser tipo cruz y creando dos variables wue el usuario entre

Comment: ¿Qué parte no sabes hacer exactamente? ¿Has pensado cómo resolverías el problema "sin programar"? (o sea, qué pasos debería seguir tu programa para cumplir el objetivo). Ese es el primer y más importante paso, pues una vez tienes la idea, y la escribes en "pseudocódigo" convertirlo en una implementación concreta (como python) suele ser ya cuestión de dar con la sintaxis correcta. Pero programar no está en los detalles de sintaxis, sino en dar con las ideas de qué quieres hacer.

Comment: Quiero añadir que el problema que has elegido para empezar, está bastante lejos de ser sencillo...

Comment: nececito mas o menos la idea para hacerlo, tengo que entregar eso hoy

Comment: cuando puedas añade el ejercico

Comment: a parte de hacer la pregunta aquí, ¿has intentado algo o hecho algún tipo de esfuerzo? Si es así, estaría bien que lo expusieras para poder ayudarte

Comment: mirad aqui tenfo una idea media loca pero asi lo tengo.  nombre1 = input("Ingrese El Primer Nombre: ")
nombre2 = input("Ingrese El Segundo Nombre: ")                                                       

contador = 0
for x in range(len(nombre1)):
    if nombre1 == nombre2:
        contador = contador+1
        break

Comment: me tiene que hacer una cruz con la primera letra que tenga en comun y asi se forma el msimo nombre en forma de cruz

Comment: Buena suerte, crack! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que se trata de una tarea académica. Ya que este sitio es para ayudar a resolver problemas y dudas, pero no para hacer las tareas de los usuarios, te daré ideas de cómo resolverlo, pero no mostraré el código que implementa la solución, para que lo intentes por tí mismo a partir de las ideas proporcionadas.

Por otro lado, tampoco sabemos hasta qué nivel de Python se supone que conoces, por lo que es posible que las soluciones que te demos no fueran válidas de todas formas por utilizar características del lenguaje que aún no conoces. Por esto es mejor también una solución en "pseudocódigo" que te oriente de por dónde irían los tiros, pero no de código.

Aparte de la lectura de las cadenas, que es trivial, tienes dos tareas a resolver. Cada una de ellas podría implementarse en una función separada (si ya conoces cómo definir funciones), o en dos partes del código sin funciones. Son las siguientes:

1. Encontrar si las dos cadenas dadas tienen o no una letra en común, y si la tienen encontrar qué índice ocupa esa letra en cada una de las cadenas.

   Es decir, dadas `cadena1` y `cadena2`, obtener dos enteros que podemos llamar `i1` e `i2` que representan un índice dentro de `cadena1` (y respectivamente de `cadena2`) en los que hay dos letras iguales. Por ejemplo, si `cadena1` vale `"Hola"` y `cadena2` vale `"Abulafia"`, `i1` valdría 2 e `i2` valdría 3`, pues en`cadena1[2]`y  en`cadena2[3]`hay la misma letra (`l`)
2. Dadas dos cadenas `cadena1` y `cadena2`, así como los  índices `i1` e `i2`, imprimirlas por pantalla de modo que `cadena2` vaya en vertical, en la columna `i1` y se cruce con `cadena1` en la letra indicada por `i2`

   Siguiendo con el ejemplo anterior, `cadena1="Hola"`, `cadena2="Abulafia"`, `i1=2`, `i2=3`, debería producir el resultado:

   ```
     A
     b
     u
   Hola
     a
     f
     i
     a
   ```

Vamos con las pistas de cómo resolver cada apartado.

### 1. Encontrar la letra común

Puedes iterar por las letras de `cadena1` y para cada una de ellas comprobar si esa letra está dentro de `cadena2`. En el momento que encuentres que es así, retornarás el índice por el que estabas iterando la `cadena1` en ese momento, y la posición dentro de `cadena2` en que apareció la letra.

En el ejemplo anterior, `cadena1="Hola"`, por lo que irías iterando por las letras `"H"` (que no está en `cadena2`), `"o"` (tampoco) y al llegar a `"l"`, que sí está, obtendrías la posición en la que aparece `"l"` dentro de `cadena2` (es la posición 3), y por dónde íbamos en `cadena1` (íbamos por el índice 2). Así que retornarías `(2,3)`, que serían `i1` e `i2` respectivamente.

### 2. Imprimirlas de modo que se crucen

Iterando por las letras de `cadena2`, imprimes una letra de cada vez, pero precedida de el número adecuado de espacios, para que se "cruce" con la otra palabra en la letra correcta. ¿Cuál es ese número de espacios? El valor de `i1` antes hallado. Así imprimirias `"A"` precedida de dos espacios, `"b"` precedida de dos espacios, etc. hasta llegar al instante en que la letra que toca escribir es la que está en el índice `i2`. En ese momento en vez de escribir la letra, escribes la palabra `cadena2` completa. Después continúas con el resto de letras de `cadena1` del mismo modo.

Es decir, en pseudocódigo:

```
para cada índice en cadena2:
   si índice == i2:
      imprimir cadena1
   si no:
      imprimir la letra de cadena2 precedida de i1 espacios
```

Puedes verificar mentalmente (o en un papel) que esto funcinará correctamente para el ejemplo anterior, con `cadena1="Hola"`, `cadena2="Abulafia"`, `i1=2`, `i2=3`.